# ASCII art converter throwing error with chr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code so far:

```
readFile = open("ascii_vals.txt", 'r')
writeFile = open("ascii_art.txt", 'w')
EOF = False

while not EOF:
    line = readFile.readline()
    if line == "":
      EOF = True
    else:
        for char in list(line):
            art = chr(int(line))
            writeFile.write(art)
```

The aim of this program is to turn a file of numbers into ASCII art. My first problem is that I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/EthanWork/Python/Python Projects/Uni 
Work/asciiNumToChar/Main.py", line 14, in <module>
  art = chr(int(line))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,51,53,44,5
```

Secondly, using the `for char in list(line)` it only operates on the single digit. For example, if the number 51 is used it is split into 5 and 1 I don't want that as they will give a different result if used within the `chr()` function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

```
for char in list(line):
```

`line` has commas in it. You have to split it up on the commas. Calling `list` won't do that. Instead:

```
for char in line.strip().split(",")
```

And in the next line:

```
    art = chr(int(line))
```

you should be converting `char` to an `int`, not the whole line.

```
    art = chr(int(char))
```

But this might still fail if you have data that isn't quite as correct as you think. To trap against this:

```
    try:
        art = chr(int(char))
    except ValueError:
        art = " "
        print ("Invalid data in this line:", line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have made these changes and when i  use the for loop and then try to print char it gives me the results as expected (53 52 56 etc...) but when i add the art = bit it throws gives me an error. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '

Comment: do i need to add another for loop to strip the '' from the list of numbers?

Comment: I don't have your data so I can't verify this, but it looks as though somewhere in your file you have a pair of commas with no number between, or a trailing comma at the end of the line, or a space before a comma. I've edited the answer to put a trap in for this.